# Aligning two elements in perfect middle

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to CSS and have been learning it.

I cannot seem to figure out how to make the 2 elements in the Div to perfectly vertically align with one another. I have been reading lots and lots of articles but I still cannot get my head around what I am doing wrong.

I have attached my code - your help would be great in my journey of learning.

Thank you!

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


}
.center {}
.container1 {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
.box-1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 33%;
}
.box-2 {
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
  flex: 33%;
}
.box-3 {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
  flex: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="box-1">
      <div class="center">
        <h1>I am box number 1</h1>
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/303" alt="Cute pupies">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h1>I am box number 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box-3">
      <h2>I am box number 3</h2>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try `flex-direction: column;` it will make them appear on top of each other.

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


}
.center {}
.container1 {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
.box-1 {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 33%;
}
.box-2 {
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
  flex: 33%;
}
.box-3 {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
  flex: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="box-1">
      <div class="center">
        <h1>I am box number 1</h1>
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/303" alt="Cute pupies">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h1>I am box number 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box-3">
      <h2>I am box number 3</h2>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align the contents of the boxes, you need to add `align-items: center` to their CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For your main div block, here `.container1`, set `display` attribute to `block`. It'll work!

```
.container1 {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto; }
```